# Mapping a Json variable with "-" to Java property

Tags: java, json

I am calling a rest service which returns a JSON Object and one the field is `error-codes`. Now how do I declare a variable in Java as '-' is not allowed.

The JSON is as follows

```
 {
      "success": true|false,
      "error-codes": [...]       
    }
```

This didn't worked

```
private List<ErrorCodes> errorCodes;
```

**nor**

```
private List<ErrorCodes> errorcodes;
```

Comment: You will need to write custom deserializer

Comment: That probably depends on the mapper library you're using. Care to tell us?

Comment: I think you can cleverly do one thing, just get the response and replace "error-codes" to whatever value you want and then map it object which you want. It should work

Comment: Which json library you are using, Jackson?

Comment: Yes I am using Jackson Library

Comment: @Vipul that is not clever, it's a pretty ugly workaround. But yes, since it works, it's probably clever.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using a JSON parser such as Jackson. In this case use:

```
@JsonProperty("error-codes")
private List<ErrorCodes> errorCodes;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what kind of deserializer you use. Most deserializers work with some annotations on the fields. For example in Jackson, you could do:

```
@JsonProperty("error-codes")
private List<ErrorCodes> errorCodes;
```